# Windows 8.1 + Android ADB = Instant BSOD (wdf01000.sys)

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, bsod, adb

The question, or rather the problem, is quite simple.
Yet, I cannot find any solution to my issue.

**The problem:** As soon as I enable ADB on my phone, and plug it into my Windows 8.1 laptop, I get a Blue Screen of Death.

**What I tried to alleviate the problem:**

- Tried to install "ADB drivers" that I found.
- Tried to install Android Studio + SDK, hoping that would replace drivers.
- Tried using "windbg", but the crash and reboot is so quick, there is no proper dump. Windows does save a dump, but "ANALYSIS_INCONCLUSIVE".

Hardware:

- Asus G750JZ laptop [ Windows 8.1 Pro ]
- Huawei Mate 10 Pro [ Android 8.0 ]
- Huawei's USB-C cable

I did read online that using a USB2.0 port might help in some cases. But, my laptop has none.
Do have an old ThinkPad around, but it has no storage, yadda yadda. To always rebuild that laptop, just so I can issue a simple ADB command or two, seems excessive.

Comment: Can you post your minidump file to a file sharing service?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is...

1. Install the Android SDK, or Android Studio full.
2. Open Device Manager
3. Turn on "show hidden devices"
4. Select the ADB driver, Properties, and Update Driver by hand.

Now, simply navigate to the latest SDK's driver and get it installed (force if need to). That's it.
For some reason, the default 8.1 driver with USB3 just BSODs. Without any clue.